# Boostrap - Modal para versión mobile

Tags: php, html, html5, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

tengo este modal en bootstrap que lo uso para mostrarlo en la versión desktop de esta manera

Lo llamo de esta manera

```
        $("#addFuel").click( function()
        {
            $('#addFuelModal').modal('toggle');
        }
    );
```

**Código del modal**

```
    {{--    MODAL ADD FUEL --}}
<div class="modal" id="addFuelModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-id="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Añadir repostaje</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="formCreateCar" method="post">
                    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                            <input type='text' id="data_fueling" class="form-control" required />
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                    </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <input type="hidden" id="usercar_id" value="{{ $car[0]->id }}">
                    <button type="submit" id="btnCreateCar" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: #025c99;">
                        Crear
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">
                        @lang('general.cancelar')
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

En formato **desktop** tiene este aspecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En formato **mobile** el aspecto es este
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es, como poder hacer para que se me vea bien en mobile, que se os ocurre?

Gracias

Comment: Si el modal está cerrado ¿El responsive funciona correctamente o ves que la web se desborda a lo ancho?

Comment: No deberías tener problema, como dice @granch, ¿estás cargando todo el sitio en vistas móviles? Porque si estás simplemente reduciendo desde el inspector de elementos, sí generaría el resultado que mencionas.

Comment: El ancho del modal, está gestionado por la clase `.modal-dialog` que en vistas inferiores a 576px (cuando ya no se aplican reglas _media queries_) pasa a tener el valor `width: auto;`, esto para ajustarse al ancho de su contenedor padre `.modal` cuyo valor siempre es `width: 100%;`

Comment: @JheymanMejia lo que dices es correcto. Pero comunmente si hay un error en el responsive del sitio y el `body` desborda a lo ancho, el `.modal` por su estilo `width: 100%` desbordará tambien. Por lo poco que se puede ver en las imágenes adjuntadas en la pregunta me parecería que está sucediendo algo de eso.